# Adding a line of text using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch files and having trouble piecing together the last steps here. My goal is purely to insert 'Test4' inbetween 2 lines of text. The text never changes and is always line 1 and line 3 (line 2 is blank within the text file). The code removes line 2 (blank) but does not insert the text.

Current txt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE ProductDataeXchangePackage [
1 
2 
3
```

Current Batch script:

```
rem Saved in D:\Temp\WriteText.bat
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ren test.txt in.tmp
set p=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (in.tmp) do (
  if "%%a"=="<!DOCTYPE_ProductDataeXchangePackage+[" if "!p!"=="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>" Echo Test4 >> test.txt
  Echo %%a >>test.txt
  set p=%%a
)
del in.tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ren test.txt in.tmp
< in.tmp (

   set /P "line1="
   echo !line1!

   set /P "line2="
   echo Test4

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

) > test.txt
REM del in.tmp
```

**EDIT**: *Output example added*

```
C:\> type test.txt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE ProductDataeXchangePackage [
1
2
3

C:\> test.bat

C:\> type test.txt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
Test4
<!DOCTYPE ProductDataeXchangePackage [
1
2
3
```

Comment: it added the new line, but did not copy the rest of the lines.

Comment: @Squashman: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman/28278628#28278628)

Comment: How do I get it to copy over the remaining lines from in.tmp to test.txt?

Comment: Plase, check your data. This method work as intended... **EDIT**: I just tested it!

Comment: The cmd screen stays up too. Only way to close it is to hit the x. thoughts?

Comment: something with the findstr"^" I believe it should have a location after it such as findstr"^" test.txt or something. That does not work exactly, but the cmd window now closes. I believe the original code did not finish executing.

Comment: What happened with this solution? The least thing you should do after received free aid is to inform the final result, particularly if you reported an error in the code _four times_! `**:(**`

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it.

```
rem Saved in D:\Temp\WriteText.bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ren test.txt in.tmp
set /p line1=<in.tmp
>test.txt echo %line1%
>>test.txt Echo Test4
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (in.tmp) do >>test.txt Echo %%a
del in.tmp
```

Comment: It deletes my original text.txt file. Not sure if it worked before deleting or not.

Comment: @user3158712, you do not have a file named text.txt in your code, nor is it in my code.  But if you are referring to test.txt then of course.  You are renaming test.txt to in.tmp.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do mean test.txt ;however, I do not want to rename test.txt to in.tmp, rather, just insert 'test4' into line 2 in-between lines 1 (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>) and line 3 (<!DOCTYPE ProductDataeXchangePackage [). Honestly I did not know I was renaming test.txt to in.tmp

Comment: @user3158712, you have to create a temp file.  Batch cannot in place edit a file.